# Angular 4 - HttpClient can't hide status code error message

Tags: angular

I send post auth request to server. I am add error hanlder for the request but I got to console error below:

> POST http://localhost:7777/auth 401 (Unauthorized)

http://prntscr.com/hdjm6h

I send 401 code from server for testing and now I don't know have remove this message.

```js
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {WebStorage} from "../singleton/web-storage";
import {environment} from "../../environments/environment";
import * as $ from "jquery/dist/jquery.slim";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import * as jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import {RequestHandler} from "../handler/request.handler";

@Injectable()
export class Auth {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
                private requestHandler: RequestHandler) {

    }

    /**
     * Check is user authorized
     *
     * @returns {Observable<Response>}
     */
    isAuthorized(): Observable<Response> {
        return new Observable((observer) => {
            let formData: Object = $.param({
                transferData: {
                    jwt: WebStorage.ssRetrieve('jwt')
                }
            });

            this.httpClient.post<Object>(environment.getUrl('/auth'), formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                }
            })
                .subscribe(
                    (response: Response) => {
                        observer.next(response);
                    },
                    error => {}// For this example, error handler is empty, just for hide most console errors
                );
        });
    }
}
```

Any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [catch](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) property of Observable as :

```
this.httpClient.post(your_url).catch((ex,caught) => {
 console.log('An exception has been caught!');
 return Observable.empty();
})
```

Here instead of returning empty Observable, you can throw error but that's what you want you to avoid. So returning empty Observable solves your case.

Comment: I is not working. I got next error `Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'` http://prntscr.com/hdneln

Comment: Have you imported catch ? import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

Comment: Thanks! It is work without `subscribe`, but what do if I need use `subscribe` if request is successfull?

Comment: You can use this.httpClient.post().catch().subscribe()  to catch and subscribe simultaneously.

Comment: When I use this construction I still get error message.

Comment: `POST http://localhost:7777/auth 401 (Unauthorized)` like I described in question